# T-SQL Unpivot with column values

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a table like below:

> ### Check |  Bill Total  | D1 | D2 | D3 | D4 | D5 |
>
> ```
> 1              100       10           2
> 2               50       10                   5    7
> ```

D1 - D5 stands for different discount type, how can I get to the following?

> ### Check |  Bill Total  | Discount Type | Discount |
>
> ```
> 1        100            D1             10
> 1        100            D3              2
> 2        100            D1             10
> 2        100            D4              5
> 2        100            D5              7
> ```

Many Thanks.

Comment: "how can I get to the following?" - by writing TSQL.....

Comment: I am looking for a way to unpivot the original table with SQL, to the way like the second table, I hope that clarify my question.

Comment: I realise that, but what have you tried?

Comment: I dump it into excel change them manually at the moment, I know there must be a better way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the example of unpivot:

```
CREATE TABLE #pvt (VendorID int, Emp1 int, Emp2 int, Emp3 int, Emp4 int, Emp5 int);

INSERT INTO #pvt VALUES (1,4,3,5,4,4);
INSERT INTO #pvt VALUES (2,4,1,5,5,5);
INSERT INTO #pvt VALUES (3,4,3,5,4,4);
INSERT INTO #pvt VALUES (4,4,2,5,5,4);
INSERT INTO #pvt VALUES (5,5,1,5,5,5);

select * from #pvt

--Unpivot the table.
SELECT VendorID, Employee, Orders
FROM 
   (SELECT VendorID, Emp1, Emp2, Emp3, Emp4, Emp5
   FROM #pvt) p
UNPIVOT
   (Orders FOR Employee IN 
      (Emp1, Emp2, Emp3, Emp4, Emp5)
)AS unpvt;

drop table #pvt
```